# How to pass object as parameter in Postgres function using npgsql

Tags: .net, postgresql, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, npgsql

In my .net implementation I want to pass .net object as parameter of stored function of postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Npgsql doesn't support User Defined Types yet. We have plans to implement it but nothing is coded right now. Sorry about that.